# My php if else statement doesnt work

Tags: php

I am setting a variable, and based on the value of that variable I wanna show something

This is what im doing in a section of my php file:

```
<?php
        if($numResults > 0)
        { ?>
            <button id="unfollow" class="button"> unfollow </button>
    <?php}

        else
        { ?>
            <button id="follow" class="button"> follow </button>
    <?php } ?>
```

The value of $numResult is 1 but it still shows both buttons!
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing error messages?

Comment: No @wumm, it just shows both buttons

Comment: The only thing I see is a missing space in <?php}

Comment: Where you have `<?php}`, try adding a space between the `php` and the `}`.

Comment: Was just gonna say, what Mir said.

Comment: Yeah, that `<?php}` will surely put a stick in your spokes. Change that to `<?php }` -  I'm just wondering why you're going through all that trouble of going in and out of PHP.

Comment: @beckinho27 If you solved it, and it isn't a question, then please consider answering your own question with the solution to your problem and mark it as accepted answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use this pattern when you're escaping HTML:

```
<?php if($numResults > 0) : ?>
<button id="unfollow" class="button"> unfollow </button>
<?php else : ?>
<button id="follow" class="button"> follow </button>
<?php endif; ?>
```